# Git roll back to previous commit that wasn't pushed

Tags: git, bitbucket

I made some changes in branch `test` on my local repository, and I wanted to push those changes to a new branch `check`. This is what I did:

```
git branch check
git add -A
git commit -m "Made some changes"
# [test 0cda02c] Made some changes
git push origin check
git checkout check
```

This created a commit, but my push to the `check` branch just created a new branch off of master. It didn't actually push my commit. Then when I did `git checkout check` it reverted my local repo to the branch `check` which is just a copy of master.

Is it possible to get back to where I was when I made my commit on branch `test`, and from there how can I push that to the `check` branch?

## Edit

`git checkout 0cda02c` gets my back to my previous commit which has the code I need. However, now I'm in a "detached HEAD" state `(HEAD is now at 0cda02c)`. How can I push my current code to the `check` branch?

`git push origin check` just returns "Everything up-to-date".

Comment: Just a note, the make-a-branch-here-and-switch-to-it command is `git checkout -b branchname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did the `git branch check`, that just created the new branch without actually checking it out. Your commit then went on the `test` branch.

All you need to do too fix this is merge the change that is on `test` into `check`. This should be a fast forward merge.

```
git checkout check
git merge test
```

Now the changes should be on `check` as well and you can push them.